# How to write sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora for new database connection

Tags: oracle, tnsnames, tnsping

I just created a new database connection from Oracle SQL Developer called `BATCHINSERT`. But when I try to `tnsping` it I get the following error.

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-APR-2016 15:28:37  

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.  

Used parameter files:  
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

This is my `sqlnet.ora`

```
# sqlnet.ora network configuration file in
# /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/network/admin
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(TNSNAMES)
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN=WORLD
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

And this is my `tnsnames.ora`

```
BatchInsert=
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SID = XE)
))
```

How to write the entry for it so I can run it from `.bat` file?

Comment: didn't get your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sqlnet.ora` sets a default domain name of `WORLD`, so your `tnsnames` entry needs to have that too:

```
BatchInsert.WORLD=
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SID = XE)
))
```

You should then be able to `tnsping` and connect using either `batchinsert` or `batchinsert.world`.

Alternatively you can remove the `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN=WORLD` line from your `sqlnet.ora`, but you may have other things already that expect that to be set.

This has nothing to do with SQL Developer unless you want to use that TNS alias in a connection definition, rather than using a `Basic` connection. If you already have a TNS entry for XE you can just use that, without defining a new entry pointing to the same service/SID.

Comment: Its running fine by adding enteries in ora files

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer doesn't by default read SQLNet.ORA

Easy fix, in Preferences, point to the directory for your TNSNames files.

[image: tns directory sql developer preferences]

If you enable THICK Driver connections and have your $ORACLE_HOME os var set, then SQLDev should see and use your SQLNet.ORA file for connectivity stuff.